# C# mysql query return error "Could not find specified column in results"

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, .net-core

In this code, I cannot find the problem, can someone help me?

```
int getids;
using (var SqlCommand = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT a.id+1 AS start FROM table AS a, table AS b WHERE a.id < b.id GROUP BY a.id HAVING start < MIN(b.id) LIMIT 1", Program.SQL.conn))
{
    var check = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    if (check.HasRows)
    {
        check.Read();
        getids = Convert.ToInt32(check["id"]);
        check.Close();
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception IndexOutOfRangeException: Could not find specified column in results: id
```

But the table exists and the columns as well, the query in phpMyAdmin works smoothly, so how do I check the field id in C#?

Comment: You have named the returned column _start_, you need to use _check["start"]_ in the conversion

Comment: @Steve Ok that fixed it, but now I get this: Exception MySqlException: Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()

Comment: You have to call `check.Read()` before calling `check["id"]`. Think of `check` as being a table, andyou are currently pointing _before_ the first row. You need to call `Read()` to point to the first row.

Comment: That error seems weird with the code posted.  Are you sure that the error still comes from the same line?

Comment: @Steve Yes, I figured it out, the query was returning empty value (no row) because no values where matching

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
"SELECT a.id+1 AS start..."
```

So you id became start

```
getids = Convert.ToInt32(check["start"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a single row with a single column. This is the exact scenario where you use ExecuteScalar instead of an ExecuteReader.
Just remember that your query could return null (there is a WHERE and an HAVING condition). So you need to check the return from ExecuteScalar before converting it to an integer

```
int getids;
using (var SqlCommand = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT a.id+1 AS start FROM table AS a, table AS b WHERE a.id < b.id GROUP BY a.id HAVING start < MIN(b.id) LIMIT 1", Program.SQL.conn))
{
    var check = SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    if(check != null)
        getids = Convert.ToInt32(check);
}
```